# ASP.NET Core 3.1 How can I redirect to the SignIn Action contained in the AccountController provided by MicrosoftIdentity

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect

I have two login methods, OpenIDConnect and Cookie based Authentication.

I provide a button for the user to choose, and I have this code that then handles the request.

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI; 

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LogIn(LogInModel model, string actionType)
    {
        if (actionType.Equals("AzureLogin")) {
            
            return RedirectToAction("SignIn", "AccountController", new { Area = "MicrosoftIdentity" });
        }
       // default Cookie Auth follows.
    }
```

When I redirect I am getting:

> `Status Code: 404; Not Found`.

How can I invoke the provided SignIn Action. .NET Docs mention this, but I would prefer not
to use the `asp-controller` property.

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing that `LogInModel` to your sign in action?

Comment: @AbdulG I do not think so as that is my own model, when I deal with local authentication.

Comment: Probably have a `HttpPost` `Action` and using a `HttpGet` request to hit it. Can't tell, this is little to no info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the *controller* should be `Account` and not `AccountController`.

e.g.

```
return RedirectToAction("SignIn", "Account", new { Area = "MicrosoftIdentity" });
```